# phonegap googlemap add unlimited marker

Tags: cordova, google-maps

I am developing a mobile app using phonegap/cordova and using JQuery Googlemap to display markers for one of the menu page.  I noticed that i can only add about 11 markers.  Is that the maximum number you can add?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Specific to Google Maps API for JavaScript, there doesn't seem to be any limit on setting Markers. However, if there's [too many markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers), its suggested that you use clustering to group sets of markers (and can be implemented id various ways)